# regex on python spiting a string into a specific sequence

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a string that may look like
`CITS/CPU/0218/2305CITS/VDU/0218/2305CITS/KEY/0218/2305`
or
`CITS/CPU/0218/2305CITS/VDU/0218/2305 CITS/KEY/0218/2305`
or
`CITS/CPU/0218/2305 CITS/VDU/0218/2305 CITS/KEY/0218/2305`
or
`CITS/CPU/0218/2305`

I was trying to come up with a regex that would match against a sequence like `CITS/CPU/0218/2305` so that I can split any string into a list that matches this case only. 
**Essentially I just need to extract the `*/*/*/*` part into a list from incoming strings**
My code

```py
product_code = CITS/CPU/0218/2305CITS/VDU/0218/2305 CITS/KEY/0218/2305
(re.split(r'^((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(.)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(.)(\\d+)(.)(\\d+)$', product_code))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have tried it ```product_code.split('CITS', 3)``` but issue is the cits keyword is variable

Comment: Is `CITS` always present? If so, try `re.match` with such as [`^CITS.*?(?=\s*CITS|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/8RQrOQ/2)

Comment: The word cits may be anything such as ```MCU```, ```SESM``` etc.

Comment: Maybe [`^[A-Z/]+[\d/]+`](https://regex101.com/r/8RQrOQ/4) would suffice if the input is consistent.

Comment: This would only return the first case.

Comment: Depending on how you use it. For mulitple lines, use with multline flag to make the `^` matfch start of each line (not only string start). [`res = re.findall(r'^[A-Z/]+[\d/]+', str, re.MULTILINE)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuruKRIwVZBXV3d2TMkWN85IFTfwMjQQt/I2MAULBLmgiSiABbydo1ECHERo49MbcRZp0CuRqCnubiKUouB/i9K1UvLzEtJzMnRKFKPi3bUjdKP1Y6OSQGS6joKwDDSASnxDfUJ8fTx9HPV5Cooyswr0QBq1vz/HwA) or you use the inline flag `(?m)` in pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `re.findall` here:

```
inp = "CITS/CPU/0218/2305CITS/VDU/0218/2305CITS/KEY/0218/2305"
matches = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+/[A-Z]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['CITS/CPU/0218/2305', 'CITS/VDU/0218/2305', 'CITS/KEY/0218/2305']
```

If you only want the first match, then just access it:

```
print(matches[0])

['CITS/CPU/0218/2305']
```

Comment: I am so sorry. I just re read my question. What I need is to extract anything that matches ```letters-slash-letters-slash-numbers-numbers```

Comment: I updated my answer, but now the output has also changed.

Comment: I apologize. Looking at your code I thought it was returning the first part only. But then I realize, that's because of my string. Thank you. Really. Thank you.